# Working with PE Section Headers in linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, compilation, header-files

I have successfully written a c++ code for finding the names of section headers and their range of virtual addresses in visual studio (working in windows XP) by reading an executable file.

Problem - Now I want to implement the same code in Linux environment.I am not an experienced Linux user , so therefore I am not aware of all the tools Linux provides. Is it possible to execute windows environment specific code in Linux . If yes how will it recognize header files such as windows.h & winNt.h.And of-course I have to make the executable file available in Linux too.

Comment: Do you want to be able to dump data about **Windows** executables when running on Linux, or do you want to be able to dump data about **Linux** executables when running on Linux? They're not at all the same...

Comment: i wanna use windows executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write the code you describe portably, using only functions described in the C++ standard. Use `std::ifstream`, not `CreatFile()`, for example.

If you can write your program in visual studio with no reference to `<windows.h>`, then it will very likely run under Linux, too.

On the other hand, if all you are trying to do is to list the section headrs, try `objdump -x foo.exe`.

Comment: Linux is not recognizing IMAGE_SECTION_HEADERS and stuff.All of this reside in winNt.h header file.How am i supposed to work without it ?

Comment: You'll need to re-implement yourself any data structures that you are now getting from winnt.h.

Comment: does that mean writing the whole header file myself ?

Comment: No, there are many things in winnt.h unrelated to PE header format. You only need to re-implement the parts that you are using. On the other hand, if all you are trying to do is to list the section headrs, try `objdump -x foo.exe`.

Comment: i wrote the header file (elements from winNt.h) myself , and tried to implement the same code.Its not working . There are no compiler errors , the output is givin random values ? should i show you the code ? plz help